# Authorization through Apache Ranger in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, authorization, apache-ranger

We have ranger policies defined on hive table and authorization works as expected when we use hive cli and beeline. But when we access those hive tables using spark-shell or spark-submit it does not work.

Is there any way to set it up?

**Problem Statement:**
Ranger secures Hive (JDBC) server only. But Spark does not interact with HS2, but directly interacts with Metastore. Hence, the only way to use Ranger policies if you use Hive via JDBC. Another option is HDFS or Storage ACLs, which are coarse grain control over file path etc. You can use Ranger to manage HDFS ACLs as well. In such scenario spark will be bound by those policies. But, if I use Ranger to manage HDFS ACLS, as you mentioned it will coarse grain control over file. I might have few fine grained use cases at row/column level

Comment: #rikamamanus Please reply to the updated question

Answer (score 0):

Check for ranger audits in ranger ui and check for the denied results for those tables, verify the user.

Comment: rikamamanus - The problem is Ranger secures Hive (JDBC) server only. But Spark does not interact with HS2, but directly interacts with Metastore. Hence, the only way to use Ranger policies if you use Hive via JDBC. Another option is HDFS or Storage ACLs, which are coarse grain control over file path etc. You can use Ranger to manage HDFS ACLs as well. In such scenario spark will be bound by those policies.
But, if I use Ranger to manage HDFS ACLS, as you mentioned it will coarse grain control over file. I might have few fine grained use cases at row/column level

Comment: Can anyone help me if there are any limitations of the approach here or any way to implement similar to what have been done here?
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/RANGER-2128
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SUBMARINE-409